# Name of collage or embroidery mixing pearls, sequins and beads

Tags: terminology, embroidery, beads

Does anyone know if this type of collage or embroidery mixing different objects like pearls, sequins, beads and bugle beads has a specific name?

[image]

I found other examples on Google searching `pearls, sequins and beads embroidery` but I wonder if there is a common denomination for this type of embroidery using multiple elements.

Answer (score 6):

Consider **[beading](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/beading)**, being the decoration of fabric with beads.

Or, more specifically to embroidery, **[bead embroidery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bead_embroidery)**.

Answer (score 4):

At first I was going to say this isn't really a collage, since it's sewn rather than glued, but I learned that this *does* qualify as a [three-dimensional collage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collage#Three-dimensional_collage).

> A 3D collage is the art of putting altogether three-dimensional objects such as ... beads ... to form a new whole or a new object. Examples can include ... bead circles
>     *-- Wikipedia*

This is still a very broad category, and not specific to an embroidery-based collage. However, most beadwork is done with same-size beads, and your example includes different sizes and shapes (and some sequins thrown in).

Comment: I'm not completely satisfied with this as a definitive answer, but in case nothing more specific exists yet, I thought I'd throw it out there :)